# How to use forkJoin properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have a problem with inner Observables.

```
const wordsCollection = this.db.collection('words').valueChanges();

return wordsCollection.pipe(
      map((words: Word[]) => {
        return words.map((word: Word) => {
          const categories = word.categories.map((categoryId: string) => {
            return this.db.collection('categories').doc(categoryId).valueChanges().pipe(
              map((category: Category) => {
                return category;
              })
            );
          });
          return {
            ...word,
            categories: categories
          };
        });
      })
    );
```

and the result is something like:

```
{
word: 'blabla',
categories: Observable (instead of for example 'english')
}
```

I know I need to use something like forJoin but don't know how to use it properly. Any help?

Comment: What is `word.categories`? Is it an Array of category IDs? What are you expecting as result? An Array of {word, category} pairs?

Comment: yes, word.categories is an array with category IDs, and the result shoud get category names instead of IDs (for now each word has property 'categories' with values like ['id1', 'id2'])

Comment: then you want something like `[{word: 'blabla',
categories: ['english', 'italian']}, {word: 'buu',
categories: ['french', 'german']}`?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, these could be some suggestions for a solution.

To make things slightly clearer, at least for me, I would start creating a function which expects a `categoryId` as input and returns an Observable of the category, i.e. something like

```
function getCategory(categoryId: number) {
  return this.db.collection('categories').doc(categoryId).valueChanges();
}
```

Then I would build the Observable I need like this

```
wordsCollection.pipe(
  mergeMap(words => words),
  map(word => {
    const categoryRequests = word.categories.map(categoryId => getCategory(categoryId));
    return {word: word.word, categoryRequests};
  }),
  mergeMap(({word, categoryRequests}) => forkJoin(categoryRequests).pipe(map(categories => ({word, categories}))))
)
```

Here the key points are the following

- The first `mergeMap` flattens the `words` Array and creates an
  Observable which emits each element of the Array.
- Within the second operator, `map`, you start creating an Array of Observables which represent the requests to fetch the `category` starting from its `categoryId`, and then you return an object which has both the content of the `word` (I assume the the type `Word` has a property `word` which contains the actual word) and the category requests associated
- then I need to use `forkJoin` to execute the requests and therefore I use `mergeMap` to transform the object returned by the previous `map` operator into an Observable which emits when all requests to translate `categoryIds` into `categories` for a certain `word` have completed
- the `pipe` after `forkJoin` is just to create the object with `word` and `categories` properties

Since I do not have a Firebase environment readily available, I have simulated the Firebase Observables with the following code

```
const words = [
  {word: 'abc', categories: [1, 2, 3]},
  {word: 'cde', categories: [3, 4, 5]},
];

const categories = {
  1: 'X',
  2: 'Y',
  3: 'Z',
  4: 'X',
  5: 'W',
}

function getCategory(categoryId: number) {
  return of(categories[categoryId])
}
```

Comment: something not working, because subscribe returned me nothing (it seems the request is pending, no errors, no data).

I added debugger before forkJoin and I have this:
{
word: one word data, 
categoryRequests: observable
}

I added debugger in last map also, and this debugger didn't stop my app, code below:

      mergeMap(({word, categoryRequests}) => {
        debugger;
        return forkJoin(categoryRequests).pipe(
          map(categories => {
            debugger;
            return ({word, categories})
          })
        );
        }
      )

Comment: I do not have a Firebase environment so I have simulated the Observables generated by Firebase. I have updates my answer with the simulation code and data.

Comment: It wasn't work because if any one of the multiple observables in the forkJoin fails, the whole stream fails. So I added:

  private getCategory(categoryId: string) {
    return this.db.collection('categories').doc(categoryId).valueChanges().pipe(take(1));
  }

and it almost work, but now when I subscribe then console.logs is trigerred twice:

{object 1}
{object 2}

and I need and array of that

Comment: ok, I added toArray() to the end of wordsCollection pipe, and it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
const wordsCollection = this.db.collection('words').valueChanges();

return wordsCollection.pipe(
  mergeMap((words: Word[]) => Rx.of(...words).pipe(
    mergeMap((word: Word) => Rx.of(...word.categories).pipe(
      mergeMap(categoryId => this.db.collection('categories').doc(categoryId).valueChanges()),
      toArray(),
      map(categories => ({
        ...word,
        categories
      }))
    ))
  ))
);
```

Comment: thx, but something not working, because subscribe returned me nothing (it seems the request is pending, no errors, no data).